# How to find the smallest of a set of numbers in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to write a batch script to find the smallest number out of the given variables:

```
set d=20
set c=30
set b=2
set a=5

(some script here)
```

How can I get the least number of them?

Comment: no such command. You have to write your own logic. See `if /?` for a starting point. You shouldn't name variables with numbers (or starting with a number). Although it often seems to work, you will get into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: it's not a good idea to name your variables starting with number. Parsing command line arguments is with higher prio than expanding the variables , so to print the value of the variable `1` you will need delayed expansion.

Comment: thanks for the answer and tip mates :D

Comment: Please provide a specific question title!!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set #1=20
set #2=30
set #3=2
set #4=5
SET "tempfile=u:\temp.###"

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('set #') DO (
 SET /a num=1000000+%%b
 ECHO !num! %%a
)
)>"%tempfile%"

FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('type "%tempfile%"^|sort') DO ECHO %%b !%%b!
DEL "%tempfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

The values are assigned to variables that start with `#`.

The `set #` command will list the variables that start `#` in the format #x=*valueof#x*; the `for /f` will assign #x to `%%a` and *valueof#x* to `%%b` (see `for/?` from the prompt for documentation)

Within the loop, add 1000000 to the value of the variable, and `echo` the sum and the variable name separated by a space. Enclosing the entire instruction in a pair of parentheses allows you to redirect the output to a file.

Then sort the file, which will contain lines where the first column has number all of the same length (assuming the values assigned are <1000000) and the variable names will appear in order of their assigned values in column 2. Echo the variable name and value (!%%b! with `delayedexpansion` invoked yields the value of the variable whose name is in `%%b`.

Where there's a will, there's a way...

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
set d=20
set c=30
set b=2
set a=5

set Smallest=%d%
if %c% lss %Smallest% set Smallest=%c%
if %b% lss %Smallest% set Smallest=%b%
if %a% lss %Smallest% set Smallest=%a%

Echo Smallest number is %Smallest%
pause>nul
```

A simpler way is to set the first number to a variable ("smallest" in this case) and then check if the second number is smaller than the current smallest one. 
If second number is smaller, set the second number to "smallest". 
After that do the same with every following number.

Comment: if you have 1000s of values, this will become a really big script. even if a single value is added it will not work.

Comment: True.
I just posted this to show a simpler solution for the current example just in case it might be more appropriate for the task that ren is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this differently. Naming the variables with a distinct prefix is required here. If that is not possible, then it would be required to create a list of the variables to compare.

```
C:>TYPE sn.bat
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set WRX_1=20
set WRX_2=30
set WRX_3=2
set WRX_4=5

SET /A "THIS_NUM=0"
SET /A "PREV_NUM=2147483647"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%a IN (`set WRX_`) DO (
    SET /A "THIS_NUM=%%b"

    IF !THIS_NUM! LSS !PREV_NUM! (
        SET "MIN_NAME=%%a"
        SET "MIN_VALUE=%%b"
        SET /A "PREV_NUM=%%b"
    )
)

ECHO MIN_NAME is %MIN_NAME%
ECHO MIN_VALUE is %MIN_VALUE%
```

Here is the output of the script.

```
C:>CALL sn.bat
MIN_NAME is WRX_3
MIN_VALUE is 2
```

Comment: to my understanding, `2` is less than `5`... You missed a `set prev_num=%%b` as last line in your `if`

Comment: @Stephan - Yikes! Yes, I did fail to do that. Edited now. Are you sure we cannot use some alternative math to make 5 less than 2?

Comment: well - might be possible in some trumpish universe...